# ParseQuery simply not running, with no response, not logs written

Tags: android, parse-platform

Why does parse not appear to be doing anything with my query whatsoever. It's almost as if the entire block is ignored..

```
    try {
        Log.w("UpdateContacts", "Attempting an update");
        List<ParseObject> result = friendshipAndUserQuery.find();
        for (ParseObject friendship : result) {
            Log.i("UpdateContacts", "Found friendship" + friendship.getObjectId());
            UserObject friend = (UserObject) friendship.getParseObject("to");
            Log.i("UpdateContacts", "Converted friendship to friend " + friend.getObjectId());
            contacts.add(friend);
            ((MainActivity) mContext).notify("UpdateContacts", friend.getObjectId() + " / " + friend.getUsername(), true);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("ParseException", e.toString());
        ((MainActivity) mContext).notify("UpdateContacts", e.toString(), true);
    }
```

I get the "attempting an update" Log, but nothing else. I can see from my Parse portal that **the query has run, my android simply gets nothing back at all..** not an empty set, nothing. No logs were made..

Comment: you need to show whats happening inside `friendshipAndUserQuery.find();` method or what  `friendshipAndUserQuery` is and where is it coming from?

Comment: I don't see any log line after `.find()` method, to be sure that it is not empty list use case

Comment: I would try and Log the size of `result`, to make sure that the `result` List isn't empty.

Comment: Ajay, `find()` is a ParseQuery method, I can't easily debug using their .aar package. gio, I will make perfectly sure it's not empty, but should it not come back with either a success or failure log regardless? Muz, how do I test the value of "result" if I can't even get it to print a log... I was doing just that..

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

Query referenced the incorrect table name (case sensitive) and Parse simply stops all related code, rather than spouting out an error..